# Eclipse: Examine classloading problems/how to inspect deeply nested variables in debug view

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, groovy, classloader

I am trying to fix some class loading problems that I ran into by examining why class loaders fail to find the respective offending class (here: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.INameEnvironment).
However, Eclipse (GGTS to be more precise) fails to show/determine the variable contents I am interested in in this regard ("path" & "res", see attached screenshot).

Is it possible to determine them somehow? I was unable to see them in the variables and watch view (other variables like ucp are inspectable). I downloaded a SDK from here https://jdk7.java.net/download.html (hoping that it is a fast debug build) but that does not seem to make a difference.
Maybe there are other means to figure out this sort of class loading (Class Not Found) problems?

Btw. I am using Groovy/Grails if that matters.

[image: screenshot]